# Use android phone as a mouse pad for computer

Tags: android, mouse

I understand this is a pretty common question, but im struggling with the concept of creating a mouse pad using my android device for my pc. So far i send udp packets from my phone containing values for up, down, left, and right.I have a udp listener on my computer (using .net), that evaluates the packets of data recieved and then based on that moves the mouse cursor. i got the main concept of moving the mouse using my phone, however i want to be able to drag my finger across the screen and have the mouse on the computer move corresponding to that. I need a starting point, I have no clue where to begin!
Thanks in advance!